# Using next-error and previous-error keybindings for grep under Auctex's LaTeX-mode

Tags: emacs, latex, grep, auctex

How can I navigate through text found by `M-x grep` using `C-x` `` ` `` and `M-g p`? These are normally bound to `next-error` and `previous-error` but in Auctex's LaTeX-mode they are re-bound to `TeX-next-error` and `TeX-previous-error`. I have tried using both `local-set-key` and `global-set-key` to rebind these keystrokes, but neither method works.

MWE: install Auctex, make a tex file, grep for something, and try the above keystrokes from within the tex buffer. Using `M-x next-error` will work, so will using the keystrokes from inside the `*grep*` buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun jpk/LaTeX-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key [remap next-error] nil)
  (local-set-key [remap previous-error] nil))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'jpk/LaTeX-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to look this syntax up in the Lisp manual, I have not encountered it before. Do you know why simply re-binding next-error and previous-error with local-set-key and global-set-key did not work?

Comment: My understanding is that a regular keybinding associates a key with a command.  A remap associates a new command with some other command.  So if it was bound on multiple keys, the remapping still takes effect.  It's in 22.13 of the ELisp manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can alias `next-error` to a command name of your own via `fset` and then use that in a rebinding.  For example, the following may be used in an emacs init file (`init.el` or `.emacs`), to retain the `M-g n` binding for `next-error` without removing `TeX-next-error` from `` C-x ` ``:

```
(fset #'afs-next-error #'next-error)
(fset #'afs-previous-error #'previous-error)
(with-eval-after-load "tex"
  (progn
    (define-key TeX-mode-map (kbd "M-g n") #'afs-next-error)
    (define-key TeX-mode-map (kbd "M-g p") #'afs-previous-error)))
```